# allure.attach.file fails with error Object of type AttachmentType is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, pytest, allure

I'm trying to attach screenshot to Allure report. However it keeps fail with error:

```
TyperError: Object of type AttachmentType is not JSON serializable
```

Here is the code in my conftest.py:

```
import pytest
import allure

@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    if report.whem == "call" and report.failed:
        with allure.step("Failure screenshot"):
        allure.attach.file(r'D:\image_01.png', allure.attachment_type.PNG)
```

Environment:
Windows 10
python 3.8
pytest 6.2.2
allure-pytest 2.8.36
pywinauto 0.6.8

Answer (score 0):

positional parameter form causes the error.
the code should be:

```
allure.attach.file(r'D:\image_01.png', attachment_type=allure.attachment_type.PNG)
```